# Updated data type in SQL is not recognized in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, types

Due to recent events I have to deal with the topic SQL databases and have been stuck on a problem for quite some time now.

I have assigned the datatype "varchar(50)" to a column and wanted to change it to "money" afterwards. In the SQL database this worked without problems, but the change is not recognized in my C# code.

I have several columns of the datatype "money" which all require a "decimal" value. But the updated column still requires a string.

```
    public Artikel_zeigen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //SQL Connection
        string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.QBig3dConnectionString;
        dataContext = new LinqToSqlDataClassesDataContext(connectionString);
        cs = connectionString;

        dataContext = new LinqToSqlDataClassesDataContext(connectionString);
        UserControlVisibility(Visibility.Visible, Visibility.Hidden,Visibility.Hidden, Visibility.Hidden);

    }



    private void SaveDocumentClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateNewArticle();
        SetAllReadOnly(true);
        txtSearch.Text = GetLastId();
    }

    public void CreateNewArticle()
    {
        QBig3d newArticle = new QBig3d();
        newArticle.Aktiv = strActive;
        newArticle.ArtikelInfo = strItemInformation;
        newArticle.Benennung1 = strDesignation1;
        newArticle.Benennung2 = strDesignation2;
        newArticle.Preis1 = decPrice1;
        newArticle.Preis2 = decPrice2;
        newArticle.Preis3 = decPrice3;
        newArticle.Preisstaffel = strPriceScale;
        newArticle.Seriennummer = strSerialNumber;
        newArticle.VerkaufsPreis = decSalePrice;
        //newArticle.Artikelnummer = intIdentNumber;

        dataContext.QBig3d.InsertOnSubmit(newArticle);
        dataContext.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

The code row "newArticle.VerkaufsPreis = decSalePrice;" asks for a string but the the Column is declared with "money" as well as other Columns, the only difference is, that it is changed afterwards.

Comment: which database approach are you following?(code first,database first)

Comment: I am following code first.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ANSI SQL has no money data type.)

Comment: MS SQL - I've tried other Datatypes as well but nothing worked

Comment: It would help if you showed us what you have instead of telling us. It's easy to interpret "told" details differently, not imagine them the way you see them, and miss the problem.

Comment: I've Updated my Post

Comment: Please include the `QBig3d` class definition and the table definition. Your question is about data types but nothing you've shown so far shows data types of the relevent column and property.

Comment: Did you run the migration after making the change in your code? Can you check if the Table Column in the database is as you say it should be? Also it helps to show us the (new) defintion of the property `VerkaufsPreis`.

Comment: when its code first approach, why did you modify database directly without having to driven from c# code?

Comment: I'm assuming that newArticle.Artikelnummer is the column/property you are referring to. Have you updated the c# property type to be the new data type?

Comment: @KingOfArrows Thank you that was the Problem!!

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that the c# property was not updated to use the new data type as in the database.

Comment: Yes off course. I think the question is what c# datatype is equal to ms sql money datatype